# Absolute value inequality - reflection

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, proof-explanation, absolute-value, alternative-proof

I'm having trouble following the solution (which is attached below) provided to this problem:

What is the area of the polygon formed by all points $(x,y)$ in the plane satisfying the inequality $||x|-2|+||y|-2| \le 4$?

Can I have an explanation of the solution (you can use a different approach to this problem if needed), especially can someone help me visualise the reflection "in the axes and the origin":

- Why does this work?
- How can I picture this quickly and efficiently?
  (keep in mind that this problem is from a Maths contest)

  [image: Solution]

Comment: Are you ok up to $|x-2|+|y-2| \leq 4$ ?

Comment: The darker triangles are overlapped by the images of the reflections of the lighter pentagon.  Consider the coordinates of the vertices of the square.

Comment: I don't understand how we can get from $|x-2| + |y-2| \le 4$ to $||x| - 2| + ||y| - 2| \le 4$.

Comment: The square b shows the solution to $|x-2|+|y-2| \leq 4$ in particular pick a coordinate in the petagon so $x,y >0$. If $(x,y) $ fits so too will $(|x|,|y|)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$||x|-2|+||y|-2|=||-x|-2|+||y|-2|$$
$$=||x|-2|+||-y|-2|=||-x|-2|+||-y|-2|,$$
so we can solve the equation
$$|x-2|+|y-2|\leq4,$$
for the first quadrant 
$$x\geq0, y\geq0,$$
and symmetically expand it.
Then we can consider the next cases.

A. $0\leq x\leq2,\quad 0\leq y\leq2$,
$$4-x-y\leq4,\quad x+y\geq 0.$$
The inner square with corners $(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2).$

B. $2\leq x,\quad 0\leq y\leq2$,
$$x-2+2-y\leq4,\quad y\geq x-4.$$
The trapeze with corners $(2,0), (4,0), (6,2), (2,2).$

C. $0\leq x\leq2,2\leq y$,
$$2-x+y-2\leq4,\quad y\leq x+4.$$
The trapeze with corners $(0,2), (2,2), (2,6), (0,4).$

D. $2\leq x,2\leq y$,
$$x-2+y-2\leq4,\quad x+y\leq8.$$
The triangle with corners $(2,2), (6,2), (2,6).$

The boundaries of each area identified, the corner points are easily reflected on the other quadrants too easy. The final appearance of the graph gives [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%7Cx%7C-2%7C%2B%7C%7Cy%7C-2%7C%5Cleq4).